# Sending objects through sockets java TCP server to android app

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I'm writing a client-server pair where the server is a java TCP server running on Linux and the client is an Android app developed in Android Studio.

I've successfully made a client-server pair that sends `Message` objects to each other, but when I try to implement similar functionality in my Android app nothing seems to happen.

The Android app works while just sending `Strings` with the `readLine()` and `println()` methods from the `BufferedReader` and `Printwriter` classes, but not with the `readObject()` and `writeObject()` from `ObjectOutput` / `InputStream` classes.

Have also tried `writeUnshared()` / `readUnshared()` methods without luck.

```
//Message.java
package Message;
import java.io.*;

public class Message implements Serializable {
    String msg;
    String tag;
    String username;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4L;
        // Methods.
    }

    // Reading MessageObjects in Server.java.
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Message message = null;
        try {
            while ((message = (Message)reader.readObject()) != null) {
                // Processing message.
            }
        }
    }

    // Sending Message Objects in android App.
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!msgBox.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            final String msg;
            try {
                msg = msgBox.getText().toString();
                writer.writeObject(new Message(msg, CLIENT, username));
                msgBox.setText("");
                writer.flush();
                // Updating ui etc.
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
            textBox.smoothScrollBy(textBox.getMaxScrollAmount(), 100);
        }
    }

    // Connection-method in android app, initalizes streams.
    private boolean connect(String username, String address, int port) {
        boolean connected = false;
        try {
            server = new Socket(address, port);
            InputStreamReader(server.getInputStream());
            reader = new ObjectInputStream(server.getInputStream());
            writer = new ObjectOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
            writer.writeObject(new Message("!newUser",AUTOMATED,username));
            writer.flush();
            connected = true;
            System.out.println("Connected!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Cannot Connect!");
            connected = false;
            // UI-things.
        }
        if(connected){
            // Thread that listens for replies.
            listenThread(); 
        }
        return connected;
    }
```

Comment: Where are these so called `ObjectInput` and `ObjectOutput` Streams declared and initialized? I don't think you are actually showing us the full problem

Comment: I think the server is working properly because i got it working with a command line-client. Added connection method from android app

Comment: So everything looks good... from what i can tell. You aren't doing any networking on the main thread correct?

Comment: Not sure what thread button-listeners run on, but i have a send-button that packs user input in a Message-object and sends it.

Comment: It does look as so that you have networking on your main thread since the onClick it usually always apart of it... Is it not working by it keeps crashing? or does it just not send anything when you click the button?

Comment: it doesnt crash, but nothing happens when i click the button

Comment: Nothing happens because you're catching the exception.  You can't network on the main thread.

Comment: That's curious, since this solution worked when i was just sending Strings back and forth. Should I make a new thread to handle sending as well then?

Answer (score 0):

- You need to create the `ObjectOutputStream` before the `ObjectInputStream`, at both ends. Otherwise you can get a deadlock.
- Your read loop is incorrect. `readObject()` doesn't return null at end of stream, so using null as a loop condition doesn't make sense. It can return null any time you send a null. The loop should terminate when `EOFException` is caught.